# Roslyn - creating a SeparatedList<T> from a yield'ed IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, ienumerable, roslyn

I am trying to build a `SeparatedList` using a dynamically-generated `IEnumerable` sequence (which is constructed by an `Enumerable.Select()` function call). The API function to create a `SeparatedList` takes two parameters, an `IEnumerable<T>` and an `IEnumerable<SyntaxToken>`. I have provided a simple function, `Repeat`, that is an infinite sequence generator which yields as many commas, in this case, as are requested.

The `SeparatedList` function appears to consume as many of the first sequence (parameter types here) as there are entries in the second sequence, which messes me up. Have I misunderstood how the function is supposed to work and has anyone else done this? Thanks

```
Syntax.SeparatedList<ParameterSyntax>(
    functionParameterTypes,Repeat(i=>Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken)))
```

(Edit: I should add that converting the `functionParameterTypes` to a `List<>` and passing another `List<>` with one fewer token than elements in `functionParameterTypes` does work but I am trying to do this without having to explicitly build the list ahead of time.)

Answer (score 0):

The XML documentation for the `separators` parameter says:

> The number of tokens must be one less than the number of nodes.

You're right that this is not what the method actually requires: The number of tokens must be one less than the number of nodes *or same as the number of tokens*. I wouldn't be surprised if this was intentional, code like `f(foo, bar, )` makes sense if you're trying to handle code that's just being written.

I think that calling `ToList()` on the sequence of parameters is the best choice here. And you don't have to use another `List` for separators, you can use `Enumerable.Repeat()` for that. For example like this ([taken from a library I wrote where I faced the same issue](https://github.com/svick/LINQ-to-Wiki/blob/master/LinqToWiki.Codegen/RoslynExtensions.cs#L39)):

```
public static SeparatedSyntaxList<T> ToSeparatedList<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> nodes, SyntaxKind separator = SyntaxKind.CommaToken)
    where T : SyntaxNode
{
    var nodesList = nodes == null ? new List<T>() : nodes.ToList();
    return Syntax.SeparatedList(
        nodesList,
        Enumerable.Repeat(
            Syntax.Token(separator), Math.Max(nodesList .Count - 1, 0)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same need to create a `SeparatedList` using a dynamically generated list of parameters. My solution was to use `SelectMany()` and `Take()` to add separators (i.e. "comma") to the parameters but then remove the last trailing comma.

```
        SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList<ParameterSyntax>(
            functionParameterTypes
                .SelectMany(param =>
                    new SyntaxNodeOrToken[]
                    {
                        param,
                        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken)
                    })
                .Take(functionParameterTypes.Count() * 2 - 1)
        );
```